# Getting the last two eigenvalues from this pretty wild matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Consider the following matrix:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1/\tau & x(Y_E-X_E) & -gX_I-xX_E & -gY_I-xX_E \\
x(\lambda/\sigma)(X_E-Y_E) & -2/\tau & (\lambda/\sigma)(g^2X_I-xY_E) & (\lambda/\sigma)(g^2Y_I-xY_E)\\
xX_E+gX_I & xY_E+gX_I & -1/\tau & g(X_I-Y_I)\\
(\lambda/\sigma)(xX_E-g^2Y_I) & (\lambda/\sigma)(xY_E-g^2Y_I) & g^2(\lambda/\sigma)(X_I-Y_I) & -2/\tau\end{array} \right)
$$

Take $\tau=1$.  It seems pretty obvious to me that two of the eigenvalues are -1 and -2.

According to this dude whose paper I'm reading, the other two eigenvalues are negative if

$$
xX_E - gX_I + (xX_E + g^2Y_I - xg(g + 1)[X_EY_I-X_IY_E])\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma}<1.
$$

How did he get to that conclusion?

## Update

Following the advice of a commenter below, I computed the characteristic polynomial of this matrix.

It is

$$
(t + \frac{2}{\tau})(t + \frac{1}{\tau})(t^2+\frac{3}{\tau} t+\frac{2}{\tau^2} + \ldots) + (\frac{2}{\tau})(t + \frac{2}{\tau})gxX_EX_I + (\frac{1}{\tau})(t + \frac{2}{\tau})(g^2X_I^2+x^2X_E^2)+(t+\frac{2}{\tau})(\ldots)+(\frac{2}{\tau})(t + \frac{1}{\tau})\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}g^2xY_EY_I+(\frac{1}{\tau})(t+\frac{1}{\tau})(-\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}x^2Y_E^2-\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}g^4Y_I^2)+(t+\frac{1}{\tau})(\ldots)+(\frac{2}{\tau}t-\frac{2}{\tau})(\frac{\lambda}{\sigma}g^3X_I^2),
$$

where $\dots$ means a lot of terms (without $t$ or $\tau$).

When I divide out the known roots -- i.e., divide by $(t + \frac{2}{\tau})$ and $(t + \frac{1}{\tau})$ -- I get

$$
(t^2+\frac{3}{\tau} t+\frac{2}{\tau^2} + \ldots) + \frac{(\frac{2}{\tau})gxX_EX_I}{(t + \frac{1}{\tau})} + \frac{(\frac{1}{\tau})(g^2X_I^2+x^2X_E^2)}{(t + \frac{1}{\tau})}+\frac{(\ldots)}{(t+\frac{1}{\tau})}+\frac{(\frac{2}{\tau})\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}g^2xY_EY_I}{(t + \frac{2}{\tau})}+\frac{(\frac{1}{\tau})(-\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}x^2Y_E^2-\frac{\lambda^2}{\sigma^2}g^4Y_I^2)}{(t+\frac{2}{\tau})}+\frac{(\ldots)}{(t+\frac{2}{\tau})}+\frac{(\frac{2}{\tau}t-\frac{2}{\tau})(\frac{\lambda}{\sigma}g^3X_I^2)}{(t+\frac{1}{\tau})(t+\frac{2}{\tau})}.
$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: This is a comment not an answer because I don't feel like doing the algebra ;-)  The missing eigenvalues are the roots of a quadratic $z^2+bz+c$.  You can find this quadratic by taking the (quartic) characteristic equation and dividing out the two factors you know already.  The quadratic has two negative roots iff $b>0$ and $c>0$; I expect that one of these conditions will be obviously true and the other will simplify (!) to the inequality you have stated.

Comment: @David does it make sense that it's taking me hours to compute the characteristic equation (by hand)?  expanding the determinant, multiplying out all the terms, canceling and rearranging, etc.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  That's probably what the author of the paper did too.

Comment: @David do you have any advice with regard to the update to my post?

Comment: It does look pretty revolting, but I guess that's to be expected.  However didn't you say in the question that you can take $\tau=1$?  That would make things a little easier.

Comment: @David even with $\tau = 1$ (or anything else), i don't see a way forward.  do you?  i'm on the precipice of giving up and solving for the eigenvalues numerically.  (also, in case it isn't obvious, my $t$ is the $z$ in your first comment.)

Comment: I'm not sure your calculations are correct.  If $t=-1$ and $t=-2$ really are eigenvalues then the divisions should go exactly and there should be no $t$s left in the denominator.

Comment: It's probable I made a minor error somewhere, but even if you take the determinant in its initial form, not every term is multiplied by $(t+1)$ and $(t+2)$. But those are clearly eigenvalues of the matrix. Unless I'm misunderstanding something. My thinking is that sufficient rearrangement of what I posted would get rid of the denominator. I just don't know how to achieve that rearrangement.